# How to store 3 random numbers in a single dimensional array and then get alerted in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
function next_question()
{


for (i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++)
{
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 0)) + 0;
ques_number[i] = a;

}

alert (ques_number[0]);


}
```

I want to create an Array, that has 3 random numbers in it and then get an alert of which numbers were stored in an Array! It seems simple but I'm doing something basically wrong here that my above code isn't working! Please help thanks

Comment: Do you get an error in the browser console? Do you define the ques_number variable as an array somewhere before you call that function?

Comment: Yeah that was it...I didnt define the Array anywhere before, defining the Array first fixed the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need

- a global variable `ques_number`,
- two local variables `i` and `a`,
- a simplified random part

```js
var ques_number = [];

function next_question() {
    var i, a;
    for (i = 0; i <= 2 ; i++) {
        a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
        ques_number[i] = a;
    }
    alert(ques_number[0]);
}

next_question();
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ques_number, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Oh right, that was so helpful thankyou, i was stuck on this for like an hour, so I guess I wasn't defining a global variable!